# Scroll on inner div

Tags: html, css

So im trying to make panels. And every panel will have a header and a content. Now i want to be able to scroll only on the content.

The css:

```
.content-div{
    float:left;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.panel-div{
    height:100%;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

.panel-content{
    padding: 5px;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
 }

.panel-header{
    height:100px;
    width:400px;
    text-align:right;
    padding:5px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="content-div">
    <div class="panel-div">
        <div class="panel-header">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-content">
           <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the panel-content div gets the full height of content-div and I cant come up with a good solution of how i make it 100% of content-div and take away the 100px from the header. I know there is the calc in css3 but is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: your markup is not valid

Comment: Your HTML appears to be incomplete?

Comment: Think some of it got lost when i copied it in. Should be fixed now. https://jsfiddle.net/zwvwvrgz/ this fiddle shows what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achiive what you want by changing the following:

```css
.content-div {
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.panel-div {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;

  /* add the following */
  padding-top: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 5px;

  box-sizing: border-box;  /* add this*/
}
.panel-header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: blue;

  /* add the following */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-div">
  <div class="panel-div">
    <div class="panel-header">
      <p>head</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-content">
      <div class="padded">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if your div is 400px, You could just make your `.panel-content` div 300px and put the scroll on that

Comment: This made the scroll part working. But the header does not show. Im guessing it is since i have overflow hidden on the content-div that it wont show the header

Comment: @user3664615, see edit.  I have added your html structure

Comment: This gives the same problem. If you add anough test paragraphs for the overflow to kick in you will see that the entire scrollbar is not showed because the content extends beyond the div. I can solve this by adding padding-bottom: -100px; to the panel-content but i think its uggly since you still wont se the entire scrollbar

Comment: @user3664615, ok I see the problem, You have padding and height 100% so the header and content divs are adding an extra 20px to your container (causing the scroller to be pushed off the bottom).  Add `box-sizing:border-box` to these divs and it will fix your problem - see above edit